# Implementation of __builtin_clz

Tags: c, gcc, cpu, simd

What is the implementation of GCC's (4.6+) `__builtin_clz`? Does it correspond to some CPU instruction on Intel `x86_64 (AVX)`?

Comment: I don't know, but if it's available, `LZCNT` seems like a likely candidate.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It should translate to a [Bit Scan Reverse](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html) instruction and a subtract. The BSR gives the index of the leading 1, and then you can subtract that from the word size to get the number of leading zeros.

Edit: if your CPU supports LZCNT (Leading Zero Count), then that will probably do the trick too, but not all x86-64 chips have that instruction.

Comment: It seems the link is broken.

Comment: Link should be fixed now.

Comment: If you compiler with `-mbmi1`, you're telling gcc that `lzcnt` is available on all CPUs that will run this binary.  (or much better `-march=haswell` or `-march=bdver2` or `-march=znver1` or whatever, to tune for a specific CPU as well as enabling instruction sets.)

Comment: Why does gcc provide `__builtin_clz` but not bit scan reverse?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/5re8vWzq8 yep, depending on instruction set both are being generated

Answer (score 35):

Yes, and no.

CLZ (count leading zero) and BSR (bit-scan reverse) are related but different. CLZ equals (type bit width less one) - BSR. CTZ (count trailing zero), also know as FFS (find first set) is the same as BSF (bit-scan forward.)

Note that all of these are undefined when operating on zero!

In answer to your question, most of the time on x86 and x86_64, __builtin_clz generates BSR operation subtracted from 31 (or whatever your type width is), and __builting_ctz generates a BSF operation.

If you want to know what assembler GCC is generating, the best way to know is to see. The -S flag will have gcc output the assembler it generated for the given input:

> gcc -S -o test.S test.c

Consider:

```
unsigned int clz(unsigned int num) {
    return __builtin_clz(num);
}

unsigned int ctz(unsigned int num) {
    return __builtin_ctz(num);
}
```

On x86 for clz gcc (-O2) generates:

```
bsrl    %edi, %eax
xorl    $31, %eax
ret
```

and for ctz:

```
bsfl    %edi, %eax
ret
```

Note that if you really want bsr, and not clz, you need to do 31 - clz (for 32-bit integers.) This explains the XOR 31, as  x XOR 31 == 31 - x (this identity is only true for numbers of the from 2^y - 1) So:

```
num = __builtin_clz(num) ^ 31;
```

yields

```
bsrl    %edi, %eax
ret
```

Comment: does this mean `std::countl_zero()` needs to test for zero?

Comment: It should be noted that GCC has `ffs` builtins, with: `ffs(x) = 1 + ctz(x)`, therefore `ffs` indexes bits from 1: while `__builtin_ctz(0)` is undefined. `__builtin_ffs(0)` is perfectly valid (and returns 0),