# Why c++ boost does not use builtin functions

Tags: c++, boost, built-in

I have long wondered why boost is not using built-in functions. Even if we are concerned with purity, I would expect it to be an option at least.

For example, the lowest_bit calculation from

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/boost/dynamic_bitset/detail/lowest_bit.hpp

```
    template <typename T>
    int lowest_bit(T x) {

        BOOST_ASSERT(x >= 1); // PRE

        // clear all bits on except the rightmost one,
        // then calculate the logarithm base 2
        //
        return boost::integer_log2<T>( x - ( x & (x-1) ) );

    }
```

involves a loop inside integer_log2 function, while it will be enough to call an appropriate version of __builtin_ctz() ???

Update: I found stackoverflow question with decoded __builtin_ctz
[Where is the source code of gcc builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538249/where-is-the-source-code-of-gcc-builtins)

```
  xor eax, eax
  rep bsf eax, edi
  ret
```

Comment: `__builtin_ctz` does not exist on every platform that boost supports

Comment: boost isn't a compiler it is a cross platform, cross compiler library. It is usually fairly optimized but not to the point where it wouldn't work accross a large number of configurations.

Comment: plus, in your example, I'd really check whether the builtin and the loop don't compile to the same machine code with a modern compiler in the highest optimization setting.

Comment: `T` is not always `unsigned int`

Comment: I would expect it to compile in a few (if not one) machine instructions (see update to the question). I  do not see matching the right version of the built-in function to T will be complicated.